# Conversion error when executing SQL Server stored procedure from Access ADODB

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, casting, explicit-conversion

The following code is stored in a procedure on SQL Server 2008 and is executed using ADODB in MS Access; I am receiving the following error when trying to execute it in Access...

> Run-time error -2147217913(80040e07)
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'fldNumericData' to data type int.

`fldNumeric` holds only the values 0,1,2,3,4, and 5 but the following statement fails...

```
SELECT  Order#, MachineID, Addr1, 
        Addr2, City, [State], Country, ZIP, Contact, Phone, Fax, email,
        Product, CAST([fldNumeric] AS INT) AS [fldNumeric], 
        CAST([AutoSub] AS INT) AS [AutoSub], Mode, [FileName]
INTO #sRst1
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
                'C:\Documents and Settings\database.mdb';
                'admin';'',tempTable) LEFT JOIN FN_qryOne() ON fldMatch =                         
                 FN_qryOne.fldMatch AND fldCutOff = FN_qryOne.fldCutOff
```

Answer (score 0):

ugly that you have to join to a function but try this:

```
SELECT  Order#, MachineID, Addr1, 
    Addr2, City, [State], Country, ZIP, Contact, Phone, Fax, email,
    Product, CAST([fldNumeric] AS INT) AS [fldNumeric], 
    CAST([AutoSub] AS INT) AS [AutoSub], Mode, [FileName]

INTO  #sRst1
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
            'C:\Documents and Settings\database.mdb';
            'admin';'',tempTable) AS FM LEFT JOIN FN_qryOne() AS F ON FM.fldMatch =                         
             F.fldMatch AND FM.fldCutOff = F.fldCutOff
```

Comment: Still throwing the error :/ ... Interestingly enough it started after I added a UDF for bankers rounding (though I haven't even implemented the function yet). This is really odd, removing the function and restarting my computer will resolve the issue.

Comment: The root of my problem must be in the way my procedure is coded though, I assume.